# VIM coloring with terminal color rules

Tags: vim, colors

In Linux bash shell, we can put colors with something like this:

Let's imagine a file color.txt with contents

```
\e[0;31m blah blah \e[0
```

If we do 'cat color.txt', it will results in

```
blah blah (red color)
```

But, if we open up color.txt in vim, it will just show the origin text.
What I want is vim displaying colored text as 'cat color.txt' do. Is there an option for this in vim?

Answer (score 1):

As [described elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/how-to-make-vim-display-colors-as-indicated-by-color-codes), you can use [this vim script](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) to conceal the escape codes and format the text via syntax highlighting.

Install it by downloading `AnsiEsc.vba.gz` version 12 from the bottom of the linked page, ungzip, open it in vim, run `:source %` in command mode.

Comment: I've done :source % and looks like the script is installed properly. But I still don't see the color in vim. Just Escape characters as plain text. Is there some key-code to initialize the coloring?